# ngResourceで保存されたid値をもとにeditページにredirectさせたい

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

ngResourceを使い、Rails側で構築したAPIを通して新しいarticleをDBに格納した後、URLに保存された新しいarticleのidを含むeditページにリダイレクトさせたいです。

/articles/new -> articles/[newで保存されたarticleのid]/edit

以下が現在のコードです。new.html.slim(articles#new)にてarticleの新規作成を行い、DBへの格納が成功すれば、直前に格納されたidをconsole.logに出力させたいのですが、上手くいきません。いろいろ試行錯誤していますが、new_article.idがundefinedになってしまいます。。ご教授いただけますと嬉しいです。よろしくお願いいたします。

= = =

new.html.slim

```
div ng-controller="ArticleController" ng-init=""

  form id="new_article" ng-submit="addArticle(article)"
    input type="text" ng-model="article.title"
    input type="submit" value="add"
```

= = =

ArticleController.coffee

```
angular.module('test').controller "ArticleController", ($scope, Article) ->

  $scope.addArticle = (article) ->
    @articleService = new Article(serverErrorHandler)
    new_article = @articleService.create(title: article.title)
    alert new_article.id
    $window.location.href = "/articles/"+new_article.id+"/edit"
    return
```

= = =

ArticleService.coffee

```
angular.module('test').factory 'Article', ($resource, $http) ->
  class Article

    constructor: (errorHandler) ->
      @service = $resource('/api/articles/:id',
        { id: '@id' },
        { update: { method: 'PUT' }})
      @errorHandler = errorHandler

    find: (id, successHandler) ->
      @service.get(id: id, ((article)->
        successHandler?(article)
        article),
        @errorHandler)

    create: (attrs) ->
      new @service(article: attrs).$save ((article) -> attrs.id = article.id), @errorHandler
      attrs

    update: (article, attrs) ->
      new @service(article: attrs).$update {id: article.id}, (-> null), @errorHandler
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$resource`で作成した [Resource::$save](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) は[Promise](http://azu.github.io/promises-book/)を返します。
[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/goforo/edit?html,js,console)

`Article::create`の戻り値を`attrs`ではなく、`$resouce::$save()`を（つまり`Promise`）を返して下さい。
それを、`ArticleController`で受け取ります。受け取った`Promise`は、`Promise::then` のコールバック関数内で結果を受け取り、リダイレクトできます。修正例として

`ArticleService.coffee` の

```
create: (attrs) ->
  new @service(article: attrs).$save ((article) -> attrs.id = article.id), @errorHandler
  attrs
```

を

```
create: (attrs) ->
  new @service(article: attrs).$save()
```

に。
`ArticleController.coffee`の

```
$scope.addArticle = (article) ->
  @articleService = new Article(serverErrorHandler)
  new_article = @articleService.create(title: article.title)
  alert new_article.id
  $window.location.href = "/articles/"+new_article.id+"/edit"
  return
```

を

```
$scope.addArticle = (article) ->
  @articleService = new Article(serverErrorHandler)
  @articleService.create(title: article.title)
  .then (new_article)->
    console.log new_article
    $window.location.href = "/articles/"+new_article.id+"/edit"
  return
```

にすれば、意図通りに動くのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。教えていただきました修正例で、意図していたことがようやく実現できました。。1週間ほどずっと悩み続けていたことがようやく解決できそうです。ご丁寧にありがとうございました。